# Using Solspace Freeform to create an entry including a file upload

Tags: plugin-freeform, upload, solspace, entry-form

I have recently been having some issues using the Solspace plugin FreeForm. I have created a front end entry form which, when submitted, creates an entry in a specified section in the CP. I have used the Element Connections feature to accomplish this. The issue I'm having is that one of the fields in the form is a file upload and it seems the form is having difficulty uploading the file and assigning it to the entry once the form submits.

What seems to be happening is that if the file field is left blank, the form submits without error and creates the entry successfully. But obviously then the entry is missing it's file in the entry data as none were uploaded.

However, if a file IS added during the form submission, once again the form submits without issue, the file gets uploaded to it's specified assets directory, but the entry itself is not created at all.

The form is being combined with FreeForm Payments too, so the form also contains some native FreeForm Stripe payment fields.

I'd really appreciate any advice on this. If anyone has experienced this before, can you share any advice on where this maybe going wrong as I'm completely stumped. There is no form error whatsoever so to my eyes, everything appears correct.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to Solspace Support on this? They're pretty good at responding and might have some additional items you can try.

Comment: I have reached out to them a couple of days ago regarding a separate issue but haven't heard back yet. I think with the COVID-19 situation, they're perhaps not as responsive as they'd usually be. Which is why I thought I'd try here